# Does mirror like wallpaper suitable for a mini dance studio at home exist?

Tags: painting, wallpaper

I live on my own and because I'm a dancer I want to use one of my spare rooms as a good rehearsal space. What I want to do is cover at least one of my walls there in a mirror-like wallpaper or something so that I can see my reflection really well. I can't afford a lot at the moment. I cant buy a huge mirror because they're expensive so I was thinking about a huge mirror sticker.

Answer (score 1):

You can get chrome mirror finish vinyl (with a self adhesive backing). To get an effective mirror effect on a wall though, the wall would need to be **very** smooth, or it would easily show distortion - think a "hall of mirrors" type effect.

Signwriter suppliers would be the place to look for it.